# AutoHotkey ComObjActivate("Excel.Application") not working properly

Tags: excel, autohotkey, msgbox, comobject

I have created the following code example to demonstrate my current code, that used to work but has stopped working during the past week (this is the beginning):

```
^!f::
    CoordMode, Mouse, Client
    WinActivate, ahk_exe excel.exe
    xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
    test := xl.ActiveCell.Value
    MsgBox % xl.ActiveCell.Value
    MsgBox, %test%
    Send, {Down}
return
```

I have the first line as is because the full code uses mouse as well to click on certain objects.
Then I activate the one Excel I have open on my computer (used to be named, but not necessary).
After this, I am trying to use the ComObjActivate("Excel.Application") in order to use excel's functionalities, but this seems not to work anymore, because the both of the following MsgBoxes are returned empty.

Why has this ComObjActivate stopped working? I have not changed the code at all, and it used to work a week ago. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For me your code snippet works as expected - showing both msgboxes with the content of the activecell.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I even tried to do this with a few different excels at a time, but I don't get anything in the msgboxes. I wonder what is going on...

Comment: maybe you can try `selection` instead of `activecell` ....

Comment: I tried to use this xl.Range("A1").Select and I get an error. I think my ComObjActivate is not working properly. However, this code worked on my coworkers computer just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Only posting this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment. The docs for application.ActiveCell mention that "The ActiveCell property fails if the active sheet isn't a worksheet."

Could you try adding this before getting the active cell?

```
 x1.Sheets("Name of Sheet").Select
```

Or maybe just see what returns from x1.ActiveSheet?